# rosdep resolve yaml-cpp not working for debian:wheezy

Tags: ros, rosdep, debian, yaml-cpp, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running
`rosdep resolve yaml-cpp --os=debian:wheezy`
doesn't yield the libyaml-cpp-dev package as expected, and instead returns an empty #apt line.

Why does this happen? The base.yaml seems to contain the correct definition:

```
yaml-cpp:
  arch: yaml-cpp
  debian:
    apt:
      wheezy: libyaml-cpp-dev
      sid: libyaml-cpp-dev
    source: {md5sum: f7fb81fd4a2fbd5022daa7686e816359, uri: 'https://kforge.ros.org/rosrelease/viewvc/sourcedeps/yaml-cpp/yaml-cpp-0.2.5.rdmanifest'}
```

Should I open a ticket for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51552/rosdep-resolve-yaml-cpp-not-working-for-debian:wheezy/) by [Felix Ruess](https://answers.ros.org/users/890/felix-ruess/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2013-01-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's probably something releated to https://github.com/ros/rosdep/issues/51 and https://github.com/ros/rosdep/issues/10

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Ruess](https://answers.ros.org/users/890/felix-ruess/) on 2013-01-06**:
That was not the problem, the os is the correct one when given as an option.
However the syntax was wrong, the os version key should come before the package manager key.
For reference, the pull request with the fix: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/326